# Meaning of "have feelings for someone"

Tags: meaning

I am wondering if this phrase always refers to romantic feelings. How do I express friendship arisen from a completely professional relationship?

For example, if I say this to my co-worker:

> I am not the best judge for this situation, because I have feelings for you. Ask George how things are supposed to play out in a professional environment.

What I want to express is that I like her and think of her as a friend, and so am not the best judge of this situation. But I don't want her to think that I have fallen in love with her.

What's the appropriate way to say this?

Comment: touchy touchy !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be an appropriate and precise way to say what you intend:

> I am too close to be the best judge for this situation, because I regard you as a friend. Ask George how things are supposed to play out in a professional environment.

The expression "to have feelings for" someone does not always mean romantic feelings.  However, in my experience unless the context strongly suggests otherwise it is likely to be taken as romantic feelings.

Comment: I would say *I am too close to be the best judge **in** this situation.*

Comment: "Regard as a friend" might not tell so much how Mr. Bennett actually feels. It says that the other person is a friend, and does not explain Mr. Bennett's lack of objectivity. "As your friend, I think I'm a bit biased" might say it better.

Comment: Is “to have emotions for someone” a phrase? Does it men the same thing as “to have feelings for someone?”

Comment: @PvtBuddie On its own I would agree. But here the phrase "regard as a friend" is linked as an explanantion of why Mr. Bennett is "too close" (i.e. lacking in objectivity) using the word *because*.  This is exactly the intent expressed in OP.  Whether such an expression is a sound argument is beyond the scope of usage alone.  That's for his interlocutor(s) to judge.